# virt-manager can't connect to libvirt

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

[image]

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.2 32 bits.

**The error doesn't show up if I start `gksudo virt-manager`.**

- `libvirt-bin` is installed.
- I don't know how to check for the daemon.
- I am a member of `libvirtd`.

Output of `ps ax | grep libvirt`:

```
9225 ? Sl 0:04 /usr/sbin/libvirtd -d
9302 ? S 0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -u libvirt-dnsmasq --strict-order --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/libvirt/network/default.pid --conf-file= --except-interface lo --listen-address 192.168.122.1 --dhcp-range 192.168.122.2,192.168.122.254 --dhcp-leasefile=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.leases --dhcp-lease-max=253 --dhcp-no-override`
```

Output of `ls -l /var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock`:

> srwxrwx--- 1 root libvirtd 0 Set 13 15:04 /var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock

Output of `getent group libvirtd`:

```
 libvirtd:x:130:OTHERUSER,MYUSER
```

#### Detailed error message

```
Unable to connect to libvirt.   
Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': Permission denied

Verify that:
 - The 'libvirt-bin' package is installed
 - The 'libvirtd' daemon has been started
 - You are member of the 'libvirtd' group

Libvirt URI is: qemu:///system

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 1185, in _open_thread
    self.vmm = self._try_open()
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 1167, in _try_open
    flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 102, in openAuth
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virConnectOpenAuth() failed')
libvirtError: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': Permission denied
```

Comment: The error doesn't show up if I start `gksudo virt-manager`

Comment: What are the contents of your `/etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf` file?

Comment: Not the perfect place, but if you're on arch like I am and installed `qemu` and `virt-manager`, try running `sudo systemctl start libvirtd` and optionally `sudo systemctl enable libvirtd` if you want it to start at startup.

Comment: Add itself to the group libvirt (and reboot): `sudo usermod -a -G libvirt <loginname>`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

An alternative to reboot/logout is to run the following commands from a terminal:

```
newgrp libvirt
virt-manager
```

The `newgrp` command allows the user to join the `libvirt` group without logout, for processes that are started in the same shell after `newgrp`. Of course this only works if the libvirt installer put you in the libvirt group, which you can check with:

```
getent group libvirt
```

Comment: this works. why isn't this ran by the libvirt/virt-manager post-install script is beyond me

Comment: This is the best answer. Until the next reboot, when it will work automatically if you are in the group.

Answer (score 100):

Rebooting the system where `virt-manager` is installed solved the issue.

Comment: not a typical Linux solution!

Comment: On 16.04 its libvirt-bin .service not libvirtd .service if you wonder. So the daemon is there.

Comment: Usually just logout/login should be enough in this case to make the group membership changes propagate into current session, but for me personally there's not much difference between relogin and reboot (causes very similar disruption, the reboot takes just about 7s longer), so I rather used reboot "just in case".

Comment: "did you try turning it off and then on again?"

Comment: Got this bug with Ubuntu 20.04 (problem with socket is still here).

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/828204/53738) from @Flatron describes the no-reboot solution.

Answer (score 81):

After installing KVM, run this command then that error will not occur again.

```
sudo virt-manager
```

Comment: whoa!!! What is this, How did this work?

Comment: It worked because of `sudo`.  read explanation in another answer https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/45805/how-to-use-virt-manager-as-a-non-root-user/?answer=52968#post-id-52968

Comment: Should be the acepted answer.

Comment: It works but needed root to use. I want to use it from normal user. What can i do for it?

Comment: Did not work for me. Turned out to be a corrupt configuration file... likely from using boxes and virt-manager on and off... or force closing boxes while it "saves" the machine state in the background without warning when you close it. `journalctl -xe _SYSTEMD_UNIT=libvirtd.service`

Comment: As @andrew-grasso states, you need to logout/login for the group membership changes to apply.  Using `sudo` is not recommended.

Comment: Running without sudo was giving you permission errors. sudo virt-manager has solved on my system.

Comment: I needed to first install `libvirt-bin` and then `sudo virt-manager` worked.

Comment: link to ask fedora is dead now :(

Answer (score 17):

For me, the error was caused because group membership changes don't apply without a logout-login (or reboot). I had just installed KVM and libvirt-bin. The installer automatically added my user to the libvirtd group, I had restarted the libvirt-bin service, but I was still getting the error.

**Don't change file permissions to 777. Don't just run everything as root or sudo to avoid understanding what's wrong.**

Simply logging out and back in resolved the problem by applying my new group membership.

Assuming you just installed libvirt-bin and already confirmed that your current user is a member of the libvirtd group as the error message suggests, you will need to log out and back in for the new group membership to apply.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 7):

Logged in user has to be added to `libvirt` usergroup

```
sudo usermod -a -G libvirt $USER
```

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: There is a incorrect guide on askubuntu that instructs people to add their user to a 'libvirtd' rather than the correct 'libvirt'. Make sure you're adding your user to the correct group

Answer (score 5):

I'm managing both Qemu and Virtualbox on my Ubuntu 14.02 machine, and after installing Virtualbox  libvirt-bin failed to autostart. So check if libvirt-bin is running:

`ps faux | grep libvirt-bin`

if you don't see it in ps output -  start in manually, then run virt-manager:

`sudo service libvirt-bin start`

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

```
systemctl start virtlogd.socket
```

was the only answer. The socket has its own daemon. 
That's unusual.

Answer (score 2):

For me the case was that when using `service libvirt-bin status` it showed that everything was just running fine though I could not connect like:

```
    ● libvirt-bin.service - Virtualization daemon
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/libvirt-bin.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: active (running) since Do 2016-09-22 13:22:16 CEST; 6min ago
[...]
```

In `/var/run/libvirt/` there should be these two files:

```
srwxrwxrwx  1 root libvirtd    0 Sep 22 13:22 libvirt-sock=
srwxrwxrwx  1 root libvirtd    0 Sep 22 13:22 libvirt-sock-ro=
```

If the sockets are not showing, use `service libvirt-bin stop; service libvirt-bin start` to completely restart the process. Using `service libvirt-bin restart` is not sufficient and will not re-create the socket.

The `libvirt-bin` service **can safely be stopped and will not poweroff the guests**.

Answer (score 2):

After installing all of the packages stated by the op, you can log out then log back in. Anything that add you to user groups you need to log out and back in to be added to the new groups. It is a minor inconvenience, less of one than rebooting.

This was flagged as not complete however this goes as a general rule for adding your user to a group. A relog is needed, that was the missing part that I did not see here.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! In its current form your answer is not as good as it could be. Could you review [How to Write a Good Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659), and [Style guide for questions and answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/89/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers). You could clarify what packages need installed.

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 19.10.

Answer (score 2):

The user in `libvirt` group can run `virt-manager` and `virsh` without `sudo`.

```
$ sudo gpasswd libvirt -a <username> 
$ cat <<EOF | tee -a ~/.profile
export VIRSH_DEFAULT_CONNECT_URI=qemu:///system 
EOF 
$ sudo reboot
```

Comment: Good answer, just can you explain a little how works your command lines? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1198894/edit) your answer

Comment: @damadam so first he adds `<username>` to the libvirt group so that that user can run virt-manager and virsh without needing to elevate privileges, then he defines the default path to connect to qemu and saves it in a file (in this case .profile) that will be sourced on startup. Then he reboots the system so that the group change will take effect.

Answer (score 2):

This was solution for me:

```
sudo apt install libvirt-daemon-system

sudo systemctl start libvirtd
```

**restart system**

Comment: That solved it for me on 20.04, libvirt-daemon-system was not installed when installing "qemu-kvm virtinst libvirt-daemon virt-manager".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is discussed on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1180281/comments/9) and the cause of this problem can be solved by installing the `xen-utils` package (`xen-utils-4.4` on Ubuntu 14.04). I previously was getting around this issue by `virt-manager` through `sudo` at the command line.

Comment: `xen` is similar to `kvm` https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KVM,  if you already have `kvm` installed do not install `xen`. It override my `kvm` installation and my vms stopped running. when I removed `xen` back vms started running.

Answer (score 1):

Various answers allude to the fact that the problem can occur due to group permissions not getting applied to the user running Virtual Machine Manager, and, the accepted answer, noting that reboot fixed the problem, quite possibly depended on reboot to give the user the group permissions on login (though reboot could potentially start services also).

In the case of Ubuntu 20.04.1 installing QEMU/KVM with apt-get did automatically start all services, and ended up resolving strictly by finding out how to give the user running Virtual Machine Manager `libvirt` group access (even though `/etc/group` did show that the user was granted the rights).

As others mention, logout/login is usually necessary to register new group permissions, but, in the case of a GNOME graphical desktop using `gdm`, logout and re-login were not sufficient to grant the GUI user new `libvirt` group rights.  In fact, logging out AND restarting `gdm`, stopping all instances of the GNOME shell), and, logging back in, was not enough.

In one scenario, the following was effective, and did not require rebooting after installation of `libvirt`:

- `loginctl terminate-user <user>` where  is the user logging into GNOME.
- `sudo systemctl restart gdm`

The `loginctl` command was obtained from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1113417/115439).

The `gdm` restart was required because after `loginctl` was run, the graphical console quit without offering a login screen (leaving only a black screen).  It was not determined whether `loginctl` always kills the graphical login mechanism, but if it does not, then the `gdm` restart may be superfluous (omitted).

For the record, in the case where this solution worked, `libvirt/KVM` was installed by installing: `bridge-utils`, `libvirt-daemon-system`, `qemu-kvm`, and `virt-manager`.  This properly started the required services without manual intervention, and automatically assigned group rights to pre-existing users with sudo rights.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same issue.
try running the virt manager with sudo

```
sudo virt-manager
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply followed [this tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/install_configure_kvm_archlinux/). What I was missing:

```sh
sudo systemctl enable libvirtd.service
sudo systemctl start libvirtd.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and in the detailed error report it talks about lack of permission to the `libvirt-sock` file. Changing the permission of the file `/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock` to 777 made it work for me.

Comment: [Changing permission masks to 0777 is *bad*.](/q/20105/175814) **Don't recommend potentially harmful actions** without explaining the consequences! -1

Comment: I wish this had context, because in my desperation it worked :(

Answer (score 0):

As of Ubuntu 17.10, I had to also add myself to group libvirt.  I had already added myself to libvirtd and did not remove myself from that group.  I do not know if both are required or not.

I did this since I noticed the contents of /var/run/libvirt were owned by libvirt instead of by libvirtd.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix: Go to accounts and change your groups to both of the `libvirt` groups.

Answer (score -1):

use Ubuntu Software to uninstall virtual manager, log out, log back in, install virtual manager, and run it normally without using sudo or even using the command line.

Comment: You could [improve](https://askubuntu.com/posts/987896/edit) your answer by expanding on why these steps are necessary instead of a simply reinstalling. Or following one of the other answers. [From Review](https://askubuntu.com/review/late-answers/787771)

Comment: That's like getting a locksmith to come to your house and drill out the whole lock set with a hole saw. He opens the door and says, "you're in". You pay and he leaves and you have no lock. Sure, that "works"