# Group memberships not visible without running su - $USER after new login

Tags: 18.04, sudo, groups

I use ubuntu 18.04.
I created a new group:

`sudo groupadd group_1`

Next I added myself to the group:

`sudo usermod -aG group_1 $USER`

After logging out and logging in it appears as if I am not a member of the group:

```
johan@johan-VirtualBox:~$ groups
johan adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare vboxsf
```

I have to run `su - $USER` for the group to show:

```
johan@johan-VirtualBox:~$ su - $USER
johan@johan-VirtualBox:~$ groups
johan adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker vboxsf group_1
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Seems your display manager does not correctly create a login shell while logging in... rebooting your system is a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After adding a group, logout+login is not enough in 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045993/after-adding-a-group-logoutlogin-is-not-enough-in-18-04)

Answer (score 0):

In a case of the currently logged-in user being added to a newly created group, a reboot of the OS might be needed for the groups command to show the new group.

Answer (score -1):

Johan:

Try with newgrp command:

```
johan@johan-VirtualBox:~$ newgrp group_1
```

With this command you can log in to a new group without reload session:

```
$ -> whatis newgrp
newgrp (1)           - log in to a new group
```

I hope I have been helpful.