# Add myself to a group, and `groups` does NOT reflect it immediately, why?

Tags: groups

Execute the two commands, that is, adding current user to `tcpdump` group, then check the result by querying `groups`. BUT, `groups` does not report I'm a member of `tcpdump` why?

Screenshot from Ubuntu 22.04:

[image]

At this time, I checked `/etc/group` file, it has been added.

```
tcpdump:x:117:chj
```

In order to see `tcpdump` listed in `groups` command, I have to completely log out my desktop session then re-login.

How come it has to be so cumbersome? Am I missing something?

Comment: Prefer to include terminal output as code formatted text. That focuses on the code only, and users can copy/paste the commands to try for themselves.

Comment: Asked and answered numerous times.  Take a look at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045993/after-adding-a-group-logoutlogin-is-not-enough-in-18-04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After adding a group, logout+login is not enough in 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045993/after-adding-a-group-logoutlogin-is-not-enough-in-18-04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `groups $USER` to see the changes. Now, you are listing the groups for the current process, which may differ if the groups database has changed.

Comment: Thanks. I realize that `man groups` refers to this behavior, although something vaguely.